# How to parse XML with namespace using JAXB

Tags: xml, namespaces, jaxb

I just start to learn about XML and JAXB, did some examples how to marshal and unmarshal the data. However, I still have problem with parsing XML with namespace. Can anyone help me with this example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Uuid xmlns:ns2="com/mypackage/test">
    <value>123456789</value>
</ns2:Uuid>
```

Here's the class I created

```
@XmlRootElement (name = "Uuid", namespace = "com/mypackage/test")
public class Uuid {


protected String value;

@XmlElement(namespace = "ns2")
public String getValue() {
    return this.value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Getting the null output

```
Uuid uuid = null;
    JAXBContext jbContext;
    try {
        jbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Uuid.class);
        Unmarshaller jbUnmarshaller = jbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        uuid = (Uuid) jbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        System.out.println(uuid.getValue());
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring a namespace on your `value` field in the `Uuid` object while your xml value element doesn't have a namespace.

Either remove the namespace in your `@XmlElement` annotation, add a default namespace to your xml with the `xmlns` attribute in your Uuid root element or add the namespace to your element explicitly ( `<ns2:value>94305</ns2:value>` )

Any of these options should resolve your problem.